# Is there a way to create a Java app that interacts with Spotify for PC?

Tags: java, android, spotify

I had an idea just like 1 hour ago. I want to make an app (on the phone) that communicates with an another app (on the PC) to interact with Spotify. During the hour between when I had this idea and now, I looked for the "Spotify Developers APIs" but I didn't find (or didn't understand) which one I should use to make an app that communicates with Spotify on the PC.
I hope someone will help me, because at the moment I'm stuck at the very very beginning of my project (I'm still searching on Internet what I want).

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Heartily (or Cordially), Burn38. (I also apologize for the bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Spotify SDK for android. They have a web api and so on the site to

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/

Comment: Thanks, as I read my post again I see that I didn't explained the problem correctly :/ I need help for the app ON the PC that interacts with Spotify on the PC like changing music, pause, play, shuffle, etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Then create a desktop web app. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/